# WebRtc2SIP: No video is been received/transmitted when made call between chrome and a SIP client

Tags: google-chrome, sip, webrtc, gateway, sipml

I am a newbie to webrtc2sip. I have setup my webrtc2sip gateway and registered to sip2sip.info as my domain. The problem is when I make video calls from chrome to any SIP client(ekiga/jitsi) the call gets connected but I am unable to see videos on both the sides.

==================================================================================
Case 1: Chrome calls SIP client
Result: No video shown on both transmit and receive side

==================================================================================
On the chrome JS console it says that  :

```
State machine: tsip_dialog_register_InProgress_2_Connected_X_2xx SIPml-api.js?svn=179:1
==session event = m_stream_video_local_added SIPml-api.js?svn=179:1
==session event = m_stream_video_remote_added SIPml-api.js?svn=179:1
==session event = m_stream_audio_local_added SIPml-api.js?svn=179:1
==session event = m_stream_audio_remote_added SIPml-api.js?svn=179:1
```

I have attached the JS console logs(case1_web2SIPClient_JSLogs.txt), wireshark trace(case1_web2SIPClient_WStrace.pcap) , webrtc2sip gateway console logs(case1_web2SIPClient_gatewayLogs.txt), sipml5 expert settings (Expert_settings.png) and config.xml (config.xml) for this case. I did not change anything in the config.xml that was generated after i built the source as mentioned in the instructions of this page (http://linux.autostatic.com/installing-webrtc2sip-on-ubuntu-1204).

I gave a try making calls between chrome and a android SIP client (CSipSimple) and the problem remains the same.

==================================================================================
case 2: SIP client calling chrome.
Result: as soon as I click answer button on chrome, the calls gets rejected.

==================================================================================
The JS console logs states that:

```
State machine: tsip_transac_ist_Proceeding_2_Completed_X_300_to_699 SIPml-api.js?svn=179:1
SEND: SIP/2.0 603 Failed to get local SDP
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 172.21.128.118:10060;rport=10060;branch=z9hG4bK-1441398960
From: <sip:tata@172.21.229.127>;tag=300647977
To: <sip:amshyam320@sip2sip.info>;tag=ZxQFfM7fIIP3rT1HINzb
Call-ID: fbdf5a11-ff9e-0072-fa8b-09525220cec6
CSeq: 1670757835 INVITE
Content-Length: 0
Reason: SIP; cause=603; text="Failed to get local SDP"
```

For this case I am attaching JS logs(case2_SIPClient2WebJSLogs.txt), wireshark dump(case2_jitsiToWeb_WStrace.pcap)

---

Configuration:

---

Chrome Version: checked on 30.0.1599.114 and even on Latest chrome version
Webrtc2sip version:  2.6.0
sipml5 Version: svn=203
ubuntu version: 12.04 (checked on both desktop and server editions)

---

Am I missing something in my setup or configuration please guide and help in moving further.

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case2:**

You're using RTCWeb-capable browser(Chrome) and trying to call a SIP client which may not be implementing some mandatory features like `ICE`,`SRTP`. Chrome uses `SRTP-SDES` and Firefox uses `SRTP-DTLS`.

Enable `RTCWeb Breaker` in `sipml5` [expert settings](http://sipml5.org/expert.htm) and check.

The `RTCWeb Breaker` is used to enable audio and video transcoding when the endpoints do not support the same codecs or the remote server is not RTCWeb-compliant.

**Case:1:**
Is audio working? and I can't see your logs.